# Yup Child Schema accessing parent value (or passing the value to the child)

Tags: yup

I have the following schema, and I am trying to determine how to allow the nested Yup.object().shape({..}) to have access to the RuleSchema validationTypeCode (or pass it to the child schema)

```js
export const RuleSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    description: Yup.string().required('Required').min(2).max(25),
    fieldId: Yup.number().required('Required'),
    validationTypeCode: Yup.string().required('Required'),
    failureAction: Yup.string().required('Required'),
    failureActionValue: Yup.string().required('Required'),
    dataEntryWorkFlowRuleValidationList: Yup.array().of(
        Yup.object().shape({
            //I need to be able to access the validationTypeCode from the parent schema
            fieldValue: Yup.string().min(5)
        })
    )
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this it worked fine for me

```
export const RuleSchema = object().shape({
  description: string().required('Required').min(2).max(25),
  fieldId: number().required('Required'),
  validationTypeCode: string().required('Required'),
  failureAction: string().required('Required'),
  failureActionValue: string().required('Required'),
  dataEntryWorkFlowRuleValidationList: array().when('validationTypeCode', (validationTypeCode, schema) =>
    schema.of(
      object().shape({
        // You have access to the the validationTypeCode
        // console.log(validationTypeCode)
        fieldValue: string().min(5)
      })
    )
  )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find an approach that works for my scenario, but I am not sure it is the best way to do it.

The schema is now:

```js
const RuleSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    description: Yup.string().required('Description Required').min(2).max(25),
    fieldId: Yup.number().required('dRequired'),
    validationTypeCode: Yup.string().required('Required'),
    failureAction: Yup.string().required('Required'),
    failureActionValue: Yup.string().required('Required'),
    dataEntryWorkFlowRuleValidationList: Yup.array().of(
        Yup.object().shape({
            fieldValue: Yup.string().when("$rule", (rule, schema) => {
                    return rule.fieldLength ?  schema.max(rule.fieldLength, 'Field Value is too long') : schema
                }
            )
        })
    )
})
```

I call the validation including the entire record being validated into the validation as context.

```js
RuleSchema.validateSync(_rule, {context: {rule: _rule }})
```